# Python string multiplication with "is" comparison is inconsistent

Tags: python, string

I know that python's "is" comparison uses the ID of the object to compare, but it seems to behave inconsistently specifically when comparing a string concatenated with itself. Up to 20, for a single character str, it returns True, then False:

```
>>>'a'*20 is 'a'*20
True
>>>'a'*21 is 'a'*21
False
```

With strings of different lengths it seems to happen wherever the total string surpasses 21:

```
>>>'abcdefghijk'*2 is 'abcdefghijk'*2
False
>>>'abcdefghijk'*1 is 'abcdefghijk'*1
True
```

But this doesn't apply to strings which are already longer than 21 characters:

```
>>>'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*1 is 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'*1
True
```

What is python doing that causes this change of behavior?

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.6.5

Comment: In Python 2.7, and I think up to around Python 3.6, identifier-like strings of up to length 20 are interened; those bigger are not.

Comment: See also: http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/

Comment: see https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes-

Comment: Unless at least one of the arguments to `is` is a simple variable name or function call, you are probably misusing `is`.

Comment: I'm not actually using `is` in this way, I just wanted to understand what was happening. I didn't know about interning! Thanks for the links, great reads.